# how to get the name of the newest folder created in a given directory using c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm creating a folder in the directory whose name is in date-format ex-20200324-0001 ,where second part is no of the folder.The folder contains .blg file. 
I need to get the name of the folder ,so i can include this sub directory and analyze the .blg file in the folder

Comment: what was your trying code?

Comment: You will have to show a minimal example and also improve your description of the problem.

Comment: Why don't you know what was the last folder you created in your application? Can't you have a variable stored with this information?